# How to invoke a 'click' when user clicks on href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire an alert when a user clicks on an anchor tag, but the alert is not being fired. The code I am trying is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/NLdTJ/

```
<a id="collapse"> Collapse</a>

$(function(){
  $('#collapse').click(function(){
      alert('here');
  });
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't appear to be loaded in your example

Comment: Actually your code works, just pick jQuery from "Choose Framework" selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is ok, but you weren't loading jQuery in your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/NLdTJ/3/

```
$(function(){
  $('#collapse').click(function(){
      alert('here');
  });
});
```

P.S.:
I've attached your code again because SO didn't let me post the answer with just a link to jsfiddle and no code :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a href before a tags become hyperlinks. Otherwise they are just anchors. TO fix it you should do the following:

```
    <a id="collapse" href="#"> Collapse</a>

    $(function(){
       $('#collapse').click(function(){
          alert('here');
       });
    });
```

Hope that helps.

(I also assumed jQuery, but your fiddle was set up with mooTools, not sure if it was on purpose. Here is my fix: http://jsfiddle.net/NLdTJ/13/)

Comment: Well, if it doesn't have a href it is not a link, but it is still clickable

Comment: The OP only wants to fire an event on click. HREF is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you prevent the default click behaviour of a link.

```
$(function(){
  $('#collapse').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('here');
  });
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/NLdTJ/15/

Comment: That's good advice. Doesn't really answer the question though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="collapse" href="#" onclick="alert('here');"> Collapse</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, just change the framework on JSFiddle to include JQuery and run on DOMReady

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your code. It will work when you pick a `jQuery` library from the Framework options on the left side of jsFiddle.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uberpudge/NLdTJ/10/) to include framework.